# Отключение команды на основе проверки валидации

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как сделать отключение команды на основе проверки валидации? Что имеется:

Класс, кастомной проверки данных:

```
public class StringLenghtRule : ValidationRule
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = 100;

    public int Min { get => min; set => min = value; }
    public int Max { get => max; set => max = value; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (value.ToString().Length< Min)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Длина строки не может быть меньше " + Min);
        }
        else if (value.ToString().Length > Max)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Длина строки не может быть больше " + Max);
        }
        else return new ValidationResult(true, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Есть VM:

```
public class NewKcexKpoViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{

    //репо
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    //поля
    private string ncex;
    private string kpo;
    private int kpodto;
    //Свойства
    public string Ncex
    {
        get => ncex;
        set
        {
            ncex = value;

            OkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            RaisePropertyChanged("Ncex");
        }
    }
    public string Kpo
    {
        get => kpo;
        set
        {
            kpo = value;

            OkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            RaisePropertyChanged("Kpo");
        }

    }
    public int Kpodto
    {
        get => kpodto;
        set
        {
            kpodto = value;

            OkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            RaisePropertyChanged("Kpodto");
        }
    }



    //команды
    public RelayCommand OkCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand CancelCommand { get; private set; }
    private string _error;

    public NewKcexKpoViewModel(IRepository _repository)
    {
        this._repository = _repository;

        //init command
        OkCommand = new RelayCommand(OkExecute, Validate);
        CancelCommand = new RelayCommand(CancelExecute);;
    }
```

Есть сама View где я использую эти правила (приведу только 1 текстбокс, остальные поля так же подключены):

```
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Kpodto" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <valid:EmptyStringRule></valid:EmptyStringRule>
            <valid:StringLenghtRule Min="3" Max="7"></valid:StringLenghtRule>
            <ExceptionValidationRule></ExceptionValidationRule>
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

Вопрос, как мне при Fail валидации отключать команду? Эти правила не позволяют поместить в свойство ViewModel не валидные данные, а значит и проверку я не могу сделать на уровне VM. Т.е. если пользователь введет в текстбокс нормальное значение, кнопка активировалась, а потом он ввел не валидные данные и сами данные в VM не попадут, но на View он будет гореть красным.

Comment: В методе CanExecute команды проверять не пустое ли значение свойства Kpodto или не равно предыдущему

Answer (score 0):

Сделаем свойство Nullable.

```
int? kpodto;
public int? Kpodto
{
    get => kpodto;
    set
    {
        kpodto = value;

        OkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        RaisePropertyChanged("Kpodto");
    }
}
```

Дальше:

```
OkCommand = new RelayCommand(okExecute, okCanExecute); //именуйте правильно, okExecute, okCanExecute.
                                                       //тогда не будет путаницы

private void okExecute(object obj)
{
    //...
}

private bool okCanExecute(object obj)
{
    return kpodto != null;
}
```

Comment: Так проблема не в проверке значений. Дело в том, что значение не попадает в VM если не прошла валидация на уровне View. Если бы дело доходило до   OkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); я бы не испытавал проблем.

Comment: @СергейТрофимов, OkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); в большинстве случаев вызывать не приходится, команда сама проверяет доступна она или нет

Comment: А как команда трекает изменения в VM?

Comment: @СергейТрофимов, я в тонкости не вдавался, вы попробуйте поставьте точку останова в метод CanExecute и сами в этом убедитесь

Comment: @Gardes, зависит от реализации команды же, может и не трекать

Comment: @АндрейNOP, все верно, в RealyCommand вроде трекает, хотя это не точно)

Comment: `RelayCommand` может вполне быть самописным

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да, поэтому я написал чтобы автор убедился трекается ли CanExecute или нет

Answer (score 0):

Как я решил эту проблему:
Добавим правило ValidationStep = UpdatedValue. Это означает, что валидация происходит после того как значение попало в VM

```
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Kpodto" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <valid:EmptyStringRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"></valid:EmptyStringRule>
                        <valid:StringLenghtRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"  Min="3" Max="7"></valid:StringLenghtRule>
                        <ExceptionValidationRule ></ExceptionValidationRule>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
```

Но тогда возникает проблема. В метод  Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) класса для проверки ввода попадают уже не значения. А сам объект привязки BindingExpression.

Изменим класс для проверки с учетом этого используя рефлексию:

```
public class StringLenghtRule : ValidationRule
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = 100;

    public int Min { get => min; set => min = value; }
    public int Max { get => max; set => max = value; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        //Получаем объект привязки
        BindingExpression bg = value as BindingExpression;
        if (bg==null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Привязка правила проверки произведена с не корректными параметрами ValidationStep");
        }
        //Тип
        var type = bg.DataItem.GetType();
        //Получаем инфо о свойстве из VM 
        var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(bg.ResolvedSourcePropertyName);
        //Получаем value из нужного свойства VM
        var val = propertyInfo.GetValue(bg.DataItem);

        if (val.ToString().Length< Min)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Длина строки не может быть меньше " + Min);
        }
        else if (val.ToString().Length > Max)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Длина строки не может быть больше " + Max);
        }
        else return new ValidationResult(true, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Не знаю насколько я правильно поступил и не изобрел ли велосипед, может все решается куда проще :)